# How to ignore .gitignore when using git worktree?

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm using `git worktree` to work with my branches.

For example:

```
git worktree add -b Foo ../Foo origin/master
```

It creates a new folder, new branch, and new worktree, as expected. However, there is no `node_modules/` in the new folder.

My `.gitignore` contains `node_modules`.

Is it nice way to create a complete folder?

I can create a perfect folder using a shell script (like `cp xxx xxx`), but I want to create perfect folder using `git worktree`.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it doesn't create `node_modules/`. You told Git to ignore those files; it's effectively unaware that they exist. Why would it create them?

Don't copy those files from your other folder (your `package.json` and lockfile may be different). Run `yarn` or `npm install` in the new directory instead.

Comment: I need cp .env from master folder now.(gitignore contains .env)
I don't want to copy .env every time.

Comment: @sonicmario, I'm not sure what tool you're using to inject variables from `.env` into your environment, but I think most of them search for `.env` files in parent directories. If you have `project/` that contains worktrees `branch1`/ and `branch2/` you should be able to put your `.env` directly in `project/` and have it affect both worktree directories.

Comment: Thanks! Chris.
My gitignore contain 100 files, so it is little effort to move all gitignored files.
I just toggle gitignore when I create worktree.