# Use of git worktree to handle git ignored node_modules/ of two existing branches or move to a different approach

Tags: node.js, git, npm, git-worktree

I have a repo with two branches, and I don't know how to handle the git ignored node_modules folder that should contain different packages in the two branches.
From my understanding, `git-worktree` is the correct approach, but I can't figure out how to use it.

Because the two branches already have many commits, I need a solution that preserve all of them.

At the moment, every time a checkout, I run:

```
rm -r node_modules
npm install
```

But because this process is not convenient, I investigated, and it looks that the [suggested](https://felixrieseberg.com/managing-node_modules-and-branches/) solution is to use `git worktree`.
[Somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52404771/how-to-ignore-gitignore-when-using-git-worktree) else, it doesn't seam the correct approach.

If it is the correct approach, I can't figure out how to use it in practice.

If I run:

```
git worktree add ./node_modules <current_branch_name>
```

I get:

```
fatal: '<current_branch_name>' is already checked out at '/some/path/my-project-folder'
```

If I run

```
git worktree add ./node_modules <other_branch_name>
```

The folder is created, but running `npm install` the packages are installed in it, making it unusable when I switch branch with `git checkout <other_branch_name>`.

If I create two folders with:

```
git worktree add ./node_modules_foo <current_branch_name>
git worktree add ./node_modules_bar <other_branch_name>
```

They are created, but not used by `npm install` unless I move the `package.json` files in them, that is not what I want and could be done also without `git worktree`.

Is it `git worktree` the correct approach for this problem and how to use it correctly?

I also investigate another approach, to specify a different installation folder in the `package.json` file, but it looks it is not an option.

Comment: Your `git worktree add ./node_modules <current_branch_name>` violates the article that you linked: “This folder can be anywhere, but it should not be in your current repo”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by what the [linked article](https://felixrieseberg.com/managing-node_modules-and-branches/) said:

Use directory `../branch1` to work on branch `branch1`:

```
git worktree add ../branch1 branch1
```

So a sibling directory.

Then likewise for `branch2`:

```
git worktree add ../branch2 branch2
```

But the article is wrong about this though:

> Whenever you run `git checkout my-feature-branch`, it'll automatically switch to that folder.

No. The worktrees are checked out at those branches, and you *cannot* change those branches in the current worktree; you will have to do `cd ../branch1` to “check out” `branch1` and likewise for `branch2`. (If you try `git checkout branch1` you will get a `fatal` error, since you have checked out `branch1` in another worktree; you will *not* automatically change the directory to `../branch1`.)

I guess the idea here is to “freeze” a branch on each worktree so that you don’t have to blow away that `node_modules` bloat on every branch change.

Just do:

```
cd ../branch1
npm install
```

And:

```
cd ../branch2
npm install
```

And then change directory back to whichever when you need to work on them again; `node_modules` (if it is untracked, anyway) won’t have been disturbed so there won’t be a need to `rm -r node_modules`.

At least that’s what I think the article is about.

Comment: Thank you, now I get the article. But this works also with ongoing branches? Let's say branch1 and branch2 already coexist in the project root folder, by running `git worktree add ../branch2 branch2` will I move it to the new directory with all his previous commits? This probably wasn't enough clear in my question, I'm going to edit it.

Comment: “will I move it to the new directory with all his previous commits”—You won’t really “move” it—the worktree can be used just like your current repository. The only restriction is that a branch cannot be checked out in multiple worktrees (this includes your “original” repo, before you added these two). So `git worktree add ../branch2 branch2` will work as long as `branch2` is not checked out anywhere else.